# Assigning an entity attribute to a variable

Tags: vba

I'm new to programming in VBA or object-oriented programming. I'm trying to get this code to work in the VBA compiler of Arena by Rockwell Automation.

I sometimes get `Error 424: 'Object required'`, and after debugging I'm referred to the `XL.Quit` at the end. Sometimes I've got an error related to the use of `ActiveEntity`. I don't know if I'm wrong getting the Excel file to work or if it's something do to with accessing the entity attributes of Arena anymore.

Can you spot the error? Or do you have a suggestion on how to find it myself?

```
Public Sub ModelLogic_RunBeginSimulation()
    Dim m As Model
    Set m = ThisDocument.Model
    Dim s As SIMAN
    Set s = m.SIMAN
    Dim FileToOpen As String
    Dim ArenaDir As String
    Set XL = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")
    ArenaDir = Mid(m.FullName, 1, Len(m.FullName) - Len(m.Name))
    FileToOpen = ArenaDir & "data.xlsx"
    XL.Workbooks.Open FileToOpen
End Sub

Public Sub VBA_Block_1_Fire()
Dim RNEG_deltaw As Double, Z_deltaw As Double, RPOS_deltaw As Double
Dim R_SI As Double, Z_SI As Double, S_SI As Double
Dim SI As Double, NumContenedor As Integer, Wo As Double, W_1 As Double, deltaW As Double

NumContenedor = s.EntityAttribute(s.ActiveEntity,s.SymbolNumber("NumContenedor"))
SI = XL.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Cells(NumContenedor, 3).value
s.EntityAttribute(s.ActiveEntity, s.SymbolNumber("deltaW")) = SI
End Sub

Public Sub ModelLogic_RunEnd()
    XL.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `XL` declared? If it's not declared anywhere, then as far as `ModelLogic_RunEnd` is concerned, it's just an undeclared `Variant`, and the VBA runtime has no way of knowing that it's supposed to have a `Quit` member method. Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module; does your code still compile? (Alt+D, ENTER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XL Object is declared as procedure-level and therefore doesn't exist in the scope of another procedure.

If you want a variable or object to be visible to all procedures, declare it at the beginning of the module, perhaps like:

```
Public XL as Object
```

That being said, you didn't declare `XL` it in the other procedure either.  Add this line to the very top of this module (and every module, ever):

```
Option Explicit
```

This will force you to properly declare and handle your variables, objects, properties, etc, and help prevent issues like this.

One more thing:  I bet you've run this code at least a few times, right?

Save your work and then **REBOOT**, right away.  Just trust me.

---

## More information:

- MSDN : [Understanding Scope and Visibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/understanding-scope-and-visibility?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [When Are You Required To Set Objects To Nothing?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/)
- Jon Skeet : [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `XL` is declared at module level, I believe the error relates to this line:

```
Set XL = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")
```

This requires Excel to be running. It appears when `ModelLogic_RunEnd()` is fired, tries to call the `.Quit()` method of Excel, but `XL` is nothing.

Try changing it to `CreateObject()` and see if that helps:

```
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```